# Why do semicolons throw error in react JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Below is part of my render method in JSX - why does the semicolon after the `})` throw an error? It's perfectly fine in normal JavaScript

```
<ul>
    {
        libraries.map(function (item) {
            return <li>{item.name.toLowerCase()}</li>;
        });
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because JSX `{}` expressions are limited to a single expression.

```
<div>{2 + 2; 3 + 3}</div>
```

..will throw an error.

However you can solve this by having two `{}` expressions

```
<div>{2 + 2}{3 + 3}</div>
```

There's no need for semi-colons if there will only be a single expression.

If you want to get all hacky about it, you can use the lesser known comma operator in expressions to do some local work, before returning the last expression separated by commas:

```
let x
...
<div>{x = 20, x}</div>
```

Which will display `<div>20</div>`

[You might not need semi-colons anywhere.](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding)

Comment: Semicolons separate statements, not expressions.

Comment: No you have it backwards. In JavaScript you don't put semi-colons after `if` or `while` statements, or `function` declarations, but you do after executing an expression - edit: actually I dunno.. you return the value of an expression in a return statement.. but not if statements. javascript is weird.

Comment: Actually it is not. Your answer is correct. Expressions are things that give you a value. Statements are things like assignments and control flow statements. Usually they are composed from exoressions. Every expression can also be a statement but not the other way round. The whole purpose of a semicolon is to end a statement. Block statements are special they dont need ending. You actually put semicolon after `if` or `while` if you dont use a block. Now if you understand the difference, it should be clear why you cannot put semicolons to places where an expression is expected.

Comment: Sulthan, actually the { code here } is the expression. The "code here" part is the statement that goes in the expression. It would seem to me that the jsx expression "{ ... } only allows for one statement. I could be wrong and maybe I'm overthinking but that's just my two cents. ETA: Sorry Sulthan, I read your second comment and that made perfect sense and said better what I was trying to say.