# Multiple function calls inside curly braces in React JSX

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple methods which render React components. I have put them inside methods to avoid calling components at multiple places with all the props. They are also being passed to another component.

```
renderComponentAbc = () => <Abc prop1={} prop2={} prop3={}/>;
renderComponentDef = () => <Def prop1={} prop2={} prop3={}/>;
renderComponentXyz = () => <Xyz prop1={} prop2={} prop3={}/>;
```

I want to render these one besides another in a component, so I tried this:

```
// Inside render method
<div>
{
    props.renderComponentAbc();
    props.renderComponentDef();
    props.renderComponentXyz(); 
}
</div>
```

But above code throws error `Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected }`.
Is this not possible without wrapping each function call in a `{}`? 
Removing `;` after function invocation doesn't help. Is it that `{}` can only evaluate one expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question

> Is it that {} can only evaluate one expression?

That is correct. You should use multiple expression blocks in your JSX if you have multiple render functions.

```
// Inside render method
<div>
  {props.renderComponentAbc()}
  {props.renderComponentDef()}
  {props.renderComponentXyz()}
</div>
```

Also, you shouldn't use semicolons in JSX expressions.

[Why do semicolons throw error in react JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885338/why-do-semicolons-throw-error-in-react-jsx)

Another possible way is by wrapping the function calls in an Array:

```
// Inside render method
<div>
  {[
    props.renderComponentAbc(),
    props.renderComponentDef(),
    props.renderComponentXyz()
  ]}
</div>
```

This will require you to add `key` props to the render methods though.

Comment: I know, but that's what I have asked in my question..that is it possible to do this without multiple braces?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: To avoid typing `{}` multiple times. Looks more elegant.

Comment: Updated the answer, you could wrap the render methods with an Array

Answer (score 3):

I do not know why you need that behavior, but it seems you can not do it.

**From React docs**: You can put any valid JavaScript expression inside the curly braces in JSX. For example, `2 + 2`, `user.firstName`, or `formatName(user)` are all valid JavaScript expressions.

An **expression** is any valid set of literals, variables, operators, and expressions that **evaluates to a single value**. The value may be a number, a string, or a logical value. Conceptually, **there are two types of expressions: those that assign a value to a variable, and those that simply have a value.**