# How do I do multiple conditional rendering inside a react Fragment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

I am new to Reactjs I have been stuck on this error since this afternoon I still have no idea how i keep getting error like `'}' expected.` or `JSX expressions must have one parent element.`

```
{
      title: formatMessage({
        id: 'accounts.table.options',
      }),
      fixed: 'right',
render: (_, record) => ( 
        <>
        {
                    
              (record?.is_activate && record?.status !== "initiating") && 
                <a onClick={() => activateAdAccount(record)}>
                  Edit
                </a>

              (record?.is_activate && record?.status !== "initiating" && record?.status !== "error" && record?.status !== "processing") &&
              <>
                <Divider type="vertical" />
                <a onClick={() => activateAdAccount(record)}>
                  Subscription Warning
                </a>
              </>
        }
        </>
      ),
},
```

I tried wrapping the statement with react.Fragment but I still getting some random syntax error. What is the preferred way of rewriting the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
      title: formatMessage({
        id: 'accounts.table.options',
      }),
      fixed: 'right',
render: (_, record) => ( 
        <>
        {record?.is_activate && record?.status !== 'initiating' && (
          <a onClick={() => activateAdAccount(record)}>Edit</a>
        )}
        {record?.is_activate &&
          record?.status !== 'initiating' &&
          record?.status !== 'error' &&
          record?.status !== 'processing' && (
            <>
              <Divider type="vertical" />
              <a onClick={() => activateAdAccount(record)}>
                Subscription Warning
              </a>
            </>
          )}
      </>
      ),
},
```

You need to both the js code blocks (i.e first condition and 2nd condition) in separate {}(curly braces). Reason: [Multiple function calls inside curly braces in React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324242/multiple-function-calls-inside-curly-braces-in-react-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare function like this, to return complex conditional elements :

```
{
      title: formatMessage({
        id: 'accounts.table.options',
      }),
      fixed: 'right',
      render: (_, record) => { 
        if (record?.is_activate && record?.status !== 'initiating') {
           return <a onClick={() => activateAdAccount(record)}>Edit</a>
        }
        else if (record?.is_activate &&
          record?.status !== 'initiating' &&
          record?.status !== 'error' &&
          record?.status !== 'processing') {
            return <>
              <Divider type="vertical" />
              <a onClick={() => activateAdAccount(record)}>
                Subscription Warning
              </a>
            </>
        }
        return null;
      },
},
```