# React JS - I don't Understand what is going on

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

In image it is saying It is expected to have ";", can someone explain ?

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';
import CartContext from './cart-context';

const defaultCartState = {
    items : [],
    totalAmount : 0
};

const cartReducer = (state, action) = {
    if (action.type === 'ADD') {
        const updatedItems = state.items.concat(item);
        const updatedTotalAmount = state.totalAmount + action.item.price * action.item.amount;
        return {
            items : updatedItems,
            totalAmount : updatedTotalAmount
        };
    }

    return defaultCartState;
}


const CartProvider = (props) => {
    const [cartState, dispatchCartState] = useReducer(cartReducer, defaultCartState);

    const adder = (item) =>{
        dispatchCartState({type : 'ADD', item : item})
    };
    const remover = (id) => {
        dispatchCartState({type : 'REMOVE', id : id})
    };


    const cartContext = {
        item: [],
        totalAmount : 0,
        addItem : adder,
        removeItem : remover
    }

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={cartContext}>
            {props.children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default CartProvider;
```

I don't know what code is saying. Picture has been attached.

Comment: `const cartReducer = (state, action) = {` should be `const cartReducer = (state, action) => {`

Answer (score 2):

In your code I see that the `cartReducer` Arrow Function has not been declared properly. You have to use `=>` not just `=`.

Here is the revised code:

```
const cartReducer = (state, action) => { // <-- Arrow Function
if (action.type === 'ADD') { 
  const updatedItems = state.items.concat(action.item); 
  const updatedTotalAmount = state.totalAmount + action.item.price * action.item.amount;
  return { 
      items: updatedItems, 
      totalAmount: updatedTotalAmount
  }; 
 } 
 return defaultCartState;
}
```

Furthermore, in JSX we do not use `;` because the JSX expressions are limited to a single expression. If you want to use multiple conditions you can use `,` instead. For example: `<p>{x === 'jsx', x}<p>`. This will display 'jsx'

For your reference:

[What does arrow function '() => {}' mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030747/what-does-arrow-function-mean-in-javascript)

[Why do semicolons throw error in react JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885338/why-do-semicolons-throw-error-in-react-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

**You are Using the Arrow Function in a Wrong way**

**Update your  `cartReducer` function like this**

```
const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
if (action.type === 'ADD') {
    const updatedItems = state.items.concat(item);
    const updatedTotalAmount = state.totalAmount + action.item.price * action.item.amount;
    return {
        items : updatedItems,
        totalAmount : updatedTotalAmount
    };
}
```

Comment: Omg, my bad, Thank you 
I didn't pay attention =))